# Uploading files with node js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, http-post

I'm trying to upload a .mp3 file to the node server in my local. I've followed 2 approaches for this:

1. Using uploadit.js as a separate file - in this,

```js
http.createServer(function(req, res){
 if(req.url == "/fileupload"){
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
   var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
   var newpath = './audio/audio.mp3';
   fs.readFile(oldpath, function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    fs.writeFile(newpath, data, function(err){
     if(err) throw err;
     res.write('<center>File uplaoded and saved</center>');
     res.end();
    });
    fs.unlink(oldpath, function(err){
     if(err) throw err;
    });
   });
  });
 }
 else{
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<div><form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
  res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
  res.write('<input type="submit" >');
  res.write('</form></div>');
  return res.end();
 }
}).listen(4200);
```

It launches the app in 4200 port and is available.

2. In Approach 2, I was trying to avoid the creation of a new port (as it is not possible when launched in env. like Heroku to access the PORT). So I tried integrating the code in the another file when it downloads the file content

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/html`));

server.listen('5001');

app.get('/uploadform', function (req, res) {
 if(req.url == "/fileupload"){
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
   var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
   var newpath = './audio/audio.mp3';
   fs.readFile(oldpath, function(err, data){
    if(err) throw err;
    fs.writeFile(newpath, data, function(err){
     if(err) throw err;
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
     res.write('<center>File uplaoded and saved</center>');
     res.end();
    });
    fs.unlink(oldpath, function(err){
     if(err) throw err;
    });
   });
  });
 }
 else{
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<div'>
  res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
  res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
  res.write('<input type="submit"');
  res.write('</form></div>');
  return res.end();
 } 
});
```

Here, when I select the file and hit the submit button, it is taking me to an error page with 404 status as below:

[image]

Tried my known possible ways, but still needed help on how to resolve this issue and upload the file smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your handler in express is `GET`, not `POST`. I'd check your verbs.

Comment: honestly i think you should spend some time on the very  basics of express

Comment: @ZadikiHassanOchola agreed! Doing it

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are saying in your code is 'when there is a get request to '/uploadform' then call the function' and then within the function you are saying if the req.url is "/fileupload" do the underlying job. how can the req.url be equal to '/uploadform' and also equal to "/fileupload" at the same time.i think the best way to do it would be

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/html`));


app.get('/uploadform', function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<div'>
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
    data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit"');
    res.write('</form></div>');
    return res.end();
  }); 
  app.post("/fileupload",function(req,res,next){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
        var newpath = './audio/audio.mp3';
        fs.readFile(oldpath, function(err, data){
            if(err) throw err;
            fs.writeFile(newpath, data, function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
                res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                res.write('<center>File uplaoded and saved</center>');
                res.end();
            });
            fs.unlink(oldpath, function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
            });
        });
    });

});
server.listen(process.env.port||'5001');
```

I hope it helps